# MonoTouch core graphics ... vs Android canvas

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

I am trying create a "real-time" plot using MonoTouch graphics i.e. the app calls a web service to get data and then plots it on a chart based on time and y-values. I can get the frame and axes of the chart working but I can't figure out how to update the chart with new data points - without redrawing the entire chart from scratch. The data simply needs to be drawn on top of the underlying chart frame - like drawing on a 'canvas'.

I have created this type of chart on Android using the canvas and it's quite simple to do. But  there does not appear to be anything like a canvas on iOS.

Any suggestions about the approach I should use with MonoTouch to create this type of chart?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

use core graphics with monotouch.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html